# ndimage's center_of_mass to calculate the position of a Gaussian peak

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to calculate the position of the peak of a Gaussian 2D distribution using `ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` and find that the center of mass is shifted from the center of the peak:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, x)
r = np.sqrt((xv-0.2)**2 + (yv)**2)
norm2d = stats.norm.pdf(r)
com = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(norm2d)
plt.imshow(norm2d, origin="lower")
plt.scatter(*com[::-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I calculate roughly the peak position of a noisy 2D Gaussian distribution without using a least-squares optimization routine?

Comment: `ndimage.measurements.maximum_position`?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida because the distribution is not well sampled I am looking for something that calculates the center of the peak rather than the maximum position in the image (the indices should be float values)

Comment: You could run your image through some smoothing filter, to even out the noise, and then look for the maximum in the smoothed image.

Comment: @Jaime Thanks, I think that would work as well although I would need to resample to a higher resolution array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the top xx% pixel, you can get the right result:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(norm2d.ravel(), normed=True, bins=100)
threshold = bins[np.cumsum(hist) * (bins[1] - bins[0]) > 0.8][0]
mnorm2d = np.ma.masked_less(norm2d,threshold)
com = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(mnorm2d)
plt.imshow(norm2d, origin="lower")
plt.scatter(*com[::-1])
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]